# How to make multiple labeling with mtext() and paste0() more efficient in R?

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to add a few lables using a combination of `mtext()` and `paste0()`. ***The result is shown in the picture below***.

I'm wondering if there could be a more efficient way (e.g., less code or using a better alternatives to `paste0()`) to achieve the same result in R?

```
plot(0, t = "n")
a = 2 ; b = 3 ; c = 40 ; d = 20 

l = c(paste0('Decisive\n', a, '%'), paste0('Substantial\n', b, '%'), 
      paste0('Positive\n', c, '%'), paste0('None\n', d, '%'))

mtext(l, side = 3, at = c(.6, .8, 1.2, 1.4), cex = .9, font = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not be more direct about associating data. Also `paste0()` is vectorized so you can combine multiple values at once (just one `paste0` needed).

```
v <- c(Decisive=2, Substantial=3, Positive=40, None=20)
paste0(names(v), "\n", v, "%")
# [1] "Decisive\n2%"    "Substantial\n3%" "Positive\n40%"   "None\n20%"
```

Comment: Hi MrFlick, I was wondering if you might know the answer to [*this interesting question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857624/r-function-that-uses-its-output-as-its-own-input-repeatedly)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this should be easier to extend, in case more labels:

```
plot(0, t = "n")
a = 2 ; b = 3 ; c = 40 ; d = 20 

myText <- paste0(c("Decisive", "Substantial", "Positive", "None"), "\n")
myPerc <- paste0(c(a, b, c, d), "%")
myTextPerc <- paste(myText, myPerc)

mtext(myTextPerc, side = 3, at = c(.6, .8, 1.2, 1.4), cex = .9, font = 2)
```